# How to sort data got from database?

Tags: c#

I have a `Details` object of type `Investigator` which I get from the database like this:

```
Investigator Details = RepositoryContext.RegistryRep.GetInvestigator(user.Id);
```

It is getting 20 number of result. Each one has property place and investigatorname.

So I want to get only details which has property place as india.

I need to sort from the total item to reduced no.of item which has property place=india

Result should be of type investigator.

How to do that?

Comment: [How do I ask a **good** question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - this is absolutely, utterly incomprehensible ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `Linq`

```
Investigator result = Details.OrderBy(x => x.investigatorname)
                      .Where(x => x.place == "india").ToList();
```